# Find row values based on if a parameter has been set

Tags: sql-server, parameters

I have a stored procedure with 2 parameters: `@Name` and `@Surname` which have to be set by an external source.

I need the stored procedure to return values based on what parameter has been set. It should "ignore" null parameters and only take set parameters into account.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ParticipantNames
WHERE --  The if below should go here... 

if(@Name iS NOT NULL) - find the row whose [NAME] column LIKE @Name else skip name comparison.
if(@Surname iS NOT NULL) - find the row whose [SURNAME] column LIKE @Surname else skip surname comparison.
if(@Name AND @Surname is NOT NULL) - find the row whose [NAME] column LIKE @Name AND whose [SURNAME] column LIKE @Surname
```

The following works if all the parameters have been set but return 0 rows when one parameter has not been set.

```
;WITH tempSearch AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM ParticipantNames f
    WHERE ((f.Name LIKE CASE WHEN @Name IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @Name END)
      AND (f.Surname LIKE CASE WHEN @Surname IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @Surname END)
...
```

I know it returns 0 rows because of the AND clause, but I don't know how to fix it.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: what about `where f.Name like isnull(@Name,'%') and f.Surname like isnull(@Surname,'%')`

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use a 'default' pattern on your queries.

The problem here is that you are projecting `NULL` out of the `CASE WHEN`, which then leads to `WHERE Column LIKE NULL`, which won't work.

What you can do is subtitute the actual column back in, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ParticipantNames f
WHERE ((f.Name LIKE CASE WHEN @Name IS NULL THEN Name ELSE @Name END)
  AND (f.Surname LIKE CASE WHEN @Surname IS NULL THEN Surname ELSE @Surname END)
```

This leads to `WHERE Column LIKE Column` in the default case, which will work.

Note however that queries like these are hard on the query optimizer, given the conditional use of a predicate. There are [several similar discussions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/160031/9433) on how best to approach the application of 'optional parameters'.

Comment: If you are using a higher level language to make the query, it would be preferable to eliminate 'unwanted' WHERE predicates altogether in the first place, rather than use hacks like this, or `ISNULL()`